# undefined reference to "function name", but function defined in .h file,and definition in .c? not able to generate .so file?

Tags: android

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
make.exe: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libasn1crt.so] Error 1 addition C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to 'CalculateMantissaAndExponent'   addition        line 694, external location: C:\android-ndk-r9c\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\arm-linux-androideabi\bin\ld.exe: .\obj\local\armeabi-v7a\objs\asn1crt\asn1crt.o: in function BitStream_EncodeReal:jni\asn1crt.c  C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to 'GetDoubleByMantissaAndExp'  addition        line 817, external location: C:\android-ndk-r9c\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows\arm-linux-androideabi\bin\ld.exe: .\obj\local\armeabi-v7a\objs\asn1crt\asn1crt.o: in function DecodeRealAsBinaryEncoding:jni\asn1crt.c    C/C++ Problem

Comment: This is my Android.mk file :- LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := asn1crt
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := asn1crt.c
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

Comment: anybody help me in this?